# Mongoose/Node: selecting element WITHOUT field/column name

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I have document like this

```
datatable: [{
    data:[
        ["ABC", 123, 10, 1],
        ["ABC", 121, 10, 1],
        ["DDE", 13, 10, 1],
        ["OPP", 523, 10, 1]
    ]
}]
```

I want to select with a parameter "ABC" and would return arrays only with "ABC" like this:

```
datatable: [{
data:[
    ["ABC", 123, 10, 1],
    ["ABC", 121, 10, 1]
]
}]
```

Im starting with this code:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
model.find({}).then(val=> {
    res.send(val)
})
})
```

I cant find ways to find the value without the fieldname.
I tried using $elemMatch. Other ways needs a matching column name with the value.

Comment: have you tried [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) ?

Comment: yes, but is not working.